# Rails, javascript not working when going to next record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my show page I have a link that takes the user to the next record, when the user clicks on the link, the next pages is loaded but my javascript won't work until I refresh the page

Model

```
...

def next_question
    self.class.where("id > ?", id).first
end

...
```

controller

```
...

def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

...
```

View

```
...

<div class="row" id="yes_no">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
        <div id="y_n_buttons">
            <%=link_to yesvote_question_path(@question, yes: true), remote: true, method: :post, id:"yes_button" do%>
                <p>YES</p>
            <% end %><%=link_to yesvote_question_path(@question, yes: false), remote: true, method: :post, id:"no_button" do%>
                <p>NO</p>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<%= link_to("Next", @question.next_question) if @question.next_question %>
```

Javascript(jquery)

```
window.onload = function() {
$( "#yes_button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#y_n_buttons" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
  });
});
$( "#no_button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#y_n_buttons" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when page onload, your buttons bind the click event. However, when you click the next page button and the new loaded DOM would not bind the `click` event, you need to use `on` to bind the event, instead of `click`

```
window.onload = function() {
$( "#yes_button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#y_n_buttons" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
  });
});
$( "#no_button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#y_n_buttons" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
  });
});
}
```

to

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', "#yes_button", function() {
    $("#y_n_buttons").slideUp( "slow", function() {
    });
  });
  $(document).on('click', "#no_button", function() {
    $("#y_n_buttons").slideUp( "slow", function() {
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: i tried the new code and it still doesn't work, is there a way just to reload the js every time?